# Python on a D drive connecting with VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

So my issue is more annoying than an actual problem.
I've been connecting my VS Code with Python, and Git Bash.

The code finally works, meaning my path to my D drive Python version works and I can run Python FileName.py in the terminal that is Git Bash inside VS Code to run it.

However, my imported classes don't show up with a color and are shown as an error.
When I hover over it, I do get the definition of the class with at the bottom, Unidentified error.
Like it's both recognized and not

I have tried a few Python related extensions, I've tried to mess with the debug settings.
I'm not sure what's going on, my guess is that VS Code doesn't see that my Python program is on my D drive.

Comment: what is the value of `"python.pythonPath"` in your global and workspace settings

Comment: @MijnNickname -What is the specific information of the class you imported and the error displayed on the terminal? Could you please provide us with examples that can minimize the recurrence of this problem?

Comment: @JillCheng I'm importing tkinter, I'm following a tutorial but even tho everything works when I run the script using Bash terminal, It's showing a ton of errors. It is also not assigning intelligence, like not showing an imported class as a class, just putting an error there.

Comment: I've just discovered that the issue is only in Tkinter, PIL doesn't have this issue. I find this all a bit weird, but maybe it will solve itself when I make a different project since the error starts as a warning in the from term, but when I hover over it, it said stuff about an older file in the folder that is no longer relevent. So maybe in a new project it might work better.

Comment: @MijnNickname  -Please check whether there is a python file named tkinter in the currently open project to avoid import confusion due to the same name as the module.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention. My current project is a tutorial, I was "smart" enough to call it Tkinter.py, that must have been the issue. However, it's working so for the rest of the tutorial I'll keep it as is and deal with the errors before I break it further. The next project won't have that